# Pandas Pivot table, Dealing with Multiple Values in column

Tags: python, group-by, pandas, pivot, pivot-table

I am working with data that contains multiple UNSPSC codes each with a different Price.
I want to get a pivot table that combines all of the prices per UNSPSC code.

Ultimately, I want to extract the top 5 UNSPSCs by their highest price.

```
UNSPSC= pivot_table(analysis, rows=['UNSPSC'], cols =['Extended Price'])
```

This definitely doesn't work. I don't want all of the columns it provides. I just want two. UNSPSC and then the aggregate price associate with the unique code.

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Index: 78 entries, 12142100.0 to 55121611.0
Columns: 21924 entries, ($ Difference, 2.70000004768) to (Quantity, 3255.19995117)
dtypes: float64(21924)
```

I also tried to pivot by

```
UNSPSC =analysis.pivot(index = 'UNSPSC', columns ='Extended Price')
```

My error was 
    ReshapeError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape

I tried to utilize groupby and aggfun=np.sum but I can't seem to get what I am looking for. 
How can I get a pivot table with that shows the sum of the prices to each unique UNSPSC?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it's what you want, but try to combine [groupby and aggregate](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/groupby.html):

```
>>> analysis = pd.DataFrame({"UNSPSC":["aa", "aa", "bb", "bb", "bb"], "ExtendedPrice": [1.1, 5.1, 3.5, 4.3, 3.0]})
>>> analysis.groupby('UNSPSC').aggregate(np.sum)
        ExtendedPrice
UNSPSC               
aa                6.2
bb               10.8
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from pandas import pivot_table
import numpy as np


UNSPSC = pivot_table( analysis, values = 'Extended Price', rows = 'UNSPSC', aggfunc = np.sum)


Pivot = UNSPSC.order(ascending = False)
 UNSPSC
12352200    350045.593750
12352100    165760.484375
12352300     96212.031250
12190000     68791.710938
12352000     62938.332031
```

This ended up working for me with the above results